# while runing DQSinstaller.exe it fails with following description why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ssms-2017, data-quality-services

I have installed sql server 2017 
and SSMS 2017 but when i run dqsintaller.exe it fails with errors 
which are as follows

Please help me resolve issue as i am newbie and still learning and working out how things works around

```
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]      * Clear the Code Member Table A_CODE_MEMBER.
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm] 
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm] (0 rows affected)
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]  
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]      * Clear the Code Group Table A_CODE_GROUP.
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm] 
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm] (0 rows affected)
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]  
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]      * Register assemblies T-SQL executable objects
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]         - Creating assemblies T-SQL registeration stored procedure.
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]  
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]      * Creating the internal_core schema
[16/03/2020 4:38:38 pm]         - Registering Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra T-SQL executable objects.
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] HResult 0x197A, Level 16, State 1
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "RegisterAssembly": 
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Ssdqs.Core.Startup.ServerInit' threw an exception. ---> Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Exceptions.ServerException: Failed to initialize configuration. ---> Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Log.LogMessageFormatException: Failed to init log configuration. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The locale identifier (LCID) 8192 is not supported by SQL Server.
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.InternalNextResult(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.NextResult()
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderSmi(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream)
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Database.DBAccess.ExecCommand()
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Database.Dao.DaoControllerBase`5.Execute()
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Log.LLogger.InitLogWriter()
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Log.LLogger.InitConfiguration()
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Log.LogMessageFormatException: 
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Log.LLogger.InitConfiguration()
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm]    at Microsoft.Ss...
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] 
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] 
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] ERROR - An error occured, check message above
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] 
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] 
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] Script process returned unexpected exit code: '1'.
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] Action 'Register data quality assemblies and stored procedures' finished with errors, aborting installation.
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] Starting installation rollback...
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] Installation rollback completed successfully.
[16/03/2020 4:38:40 pm] DQS Installer finished with errors. Please see installation log file at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\DQS_install.log
```

After changing my locale ID and and Locale Name i have successfully installed DQS server .  But when i enter the server as local server in DQS Client Application it is arising the same error again please see the following Snapshot

[image]

Comment: The locale identifier (LCID) 8192 is not supported by SQL Server. Set your locale correctly

Comment: @Tschallacka how do i set my locale ? and what value do i set it to ?

Comment: Find the account SQL server runs under, and set the locale of that account. It differs per operating system how to change the locale.

Comment: @Tschallacka I have changed locale name and id to US locale ID and Name and DSQ is installed successfully but when i open DQS Client Application i gives me the same error that the locale id is not supported but it it were the case DQS shouldnt have installed but it is installed and still giving the same errors. any idea how can i resolve it?

Comment: @Tschallacka I have attached the error pop up ss in the question and please help me out here.

Comment: what is in SetDataQualitySession?

Comment: @Tschallacka thanks for your help i have resolved the issue i have updated it in details.

Comment: Please self answer instead of posting the answer in the question. Just post that info in the answer below your question.

Comment: @Tschallacka i have posted answer please mark is right thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 days of searching and implementing different techniques i came to solution.The solution is very simple but tricky

First of all open cmd and run as administrator

then run following command

```
WMIC current useraccount get name,sid
```

Then run registory editor and go to

*HKEY_USER -> SID_as_Folder_Name -> Control Panel -> International*

There you will see your locale and LocaleName according to your local you have to change it according to SQL Server locale like in my case i cahnged **Locale = 1** and **LocaleName = en-US** .

Then Uninstall the server and reinstall the server before running command to install DSQinstaller.exe go to Services and select SQL server service

right click on it and goto properties
Select Log On Tab and select local System account radio option.

Then run CMD as administrator and locate your DQSinstaller location as in my case it was

> *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn*

then execute following command

```
DQSInstaller.exe –upgradedlls –instance MSSQLSERVER
```

after completion of installation open DSQ client application if you still getting error as in mentioned in my question detail run the following command in cmd after locating your SQL Server instance 
 run following command

```
DQSInstaller.exe -upgradedlls
```

after finishing upgradedlls you will be able to connect to DQS successfully.